# Regexp checkstyle to handle asterisk in copyright header

Tags: regex, checkstyle, xregexp

I am trying to use checkstyle  to validate copyright header in my java code from a copyright header file.

```
 <module name="RegexpHeader">
    <property name="headerFile" value="${samedir}/somefile.header"/>
    <property name="ignoreLines" value="10,11"/>
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="java"/>
    <property name="severity" value="error"/>
  </module>
```

The copyright header is added to each java file as a multiline comment

```
/***************** \n 
* Line 1 \n
* Line 2 \n
* Line 3 \n 
*****************/
```

I am having issues with handling asterisk as a first character of the line. 
I need checkstyle to read first as is without considering it as a regex

I tried to escape the asterisk with * or \* but it does not work for me. Any clue?

Comment: Don't escape anything, just put the text into your `somefile.header` file as-is.

Comment: @ThomasJensen Thanks, but I think the issue was with property name ignoreLines. This property is not supported so there was no error but changes did not get reflected.

Comment: If that was the solution you can post an answer and get points...